# C#, SYSTEM.IO Does not contain Stream

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using visual studio 2013. I want to write the image from an http response to the file,
however, the system.io class does not seem to contain the Stream class.

```
using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite("file.dat")) //the console gives identifier expected error.
    using (Stream input = http.Response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        input.CopyTo(output);
    }
```

Any suggestions as how to fix this?

Comment: seems like you are missing the declaration reference to the http object as it is not defined within the execution scope.

Comment: Stream is not a method, it is a class. Your comment states that you're getting an identifier expected error which doesn't really mesh with the title of your question. Could you post the exact error message you're getting and indicate whether it is a run-time or compiler error.

Comment: oops!! my bad!!! hehe. Was in a hurry typing.
The problem was with visual studio. It wasn't removing error message after I added the System.IO Namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right

```
using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite("file.dat")) //the console gives identifier expected error.
using (Stream input = http.Response.GetResponseStream())
{
    input.CopyTo(output);
}
```

But you need to import the namespace in a proper way like `using System.IO` that I think no error will rise

### Cause

Visual Studio 2013 is very much intelligent application or software developer toolkit. It can recognizes error or a miss-link, miss-spelling or any other problem that could harm the system or memory after execution. So in your cause it raises that error to prevent the bad execution.

Answer (score 0):

`system.io` is a **namespace**, not a class! And it's **case sensitive**: `System.IO`. And `Stream` is a class **not a method**